# Getting SUM of joined Fields in Cakephp

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I am using Cakephp 2.x and having a following issue with MYSQL selection of SUM of Joined query

I Have two tables named AccountVoucher & VoucherDetails

**AccountVoucher**

```
+----------+-------------+-------------+
|voucherId | voucherDate | Decription  |
+----------+-------------+-------------+
|    1     | 2014-07-05  | Test DFF    |
+----------+-------------+-------------+
|    2     | 2014-07-02  | Tf DrtF     |
+----+-----+-------------+-------------+
|    3     | 2014-07-05  | Tedgt afF   |
+----------+-------------+-------------+
|    4     | 2014-07-03  | hdt faF     |
+----------+-------------+-------------+
```

**VoucherDetails**

```
+-----------+-----------+-------------+-------------+------------+
| DetailsID | voucherId | DebitAmount | CreditAmount| AccHead    |   
+-----------+-----------+-------------+-------------+------------+
|     1     |     2     |  1200       |    1000     |  AB        |
+-----------+-----------+-------------+-------------+------------+
|     2     |     2     |  1000       |    700      |  AB        |
+-----------+-----------+-------------+-------------+------------+
|     3     |     4     |  500        |    400      |  GH        |
+-----------+-----------+-------------+-------------+------------+
|     4     |     3     |  1500       |    500      |  GH        |
+-----------+-----------+-------------+-------------+------------+
```

VoucherDetails Table must be joined from AccountVoucher Table and,

I need to get Total OF Debit amounts and Credit amounts for each AccHeads AB and GH,

and, result should be

```
+----------+-------------+-------------+
|AccHead   | TotalDebit  | TotalCredit |
+----------+-------------+-------------+
|    AB    |    2200     |     1700    |
+----------+-------------+-------------+
|    GH    |    2000     |     900     |
+----------+-------------+-------------+
```

Please Help...

Comment: Help with what? You don't know how to join tables? You don't know how to inject SQL expressions into find calls? You don't know how to group? Your question doesn't contain any problem description whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

The sql statement you need is *(It is not clear why you need the JOIN for the results you needed)*:

```
SELECT AccHead, SUM(DebitAmount) AS TotalDebit, SUM(CreditAmount) AS TotalCredit
FROM VoucherDetails
GROUP BY AccHead;
```

To translate that into CakePHP, within the VoucherDetail model:

```
$this->find('all',
  'fields' => array(
        'AccHead',
        'SUM(DebitAmount) AS TotalDebit',
        'SUM(CreditAmount) AS TotalCredit'),
    'group' => 'AccHead')
```

Comment: It would be cleaner to define the SUM fields as [virtualField](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html) in the model, to avoid a "random" 0 from being thrown in the resultset.

Comment: @Oldskool - Doesn't seem worth assigning a virtualField(s) if you're only needing the data in one place.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine. Load Your Model if required.

```
 $query = "select b.AccHead, sum(b.DebitAmount) as TotalDebit ,
 sum(b.CreditAmount) as TotalCredit from AccountVoucher as a ,
 VoucherDetails as b where a.voucherId = b.voucherId group by AccHead";

 $this->ModelName->query($query);
```

You can also use

```
$this->find('all',
  'conditions' => array('AccountVoucher.voucherId' => 'VoucherDetails.voucherId'),
  'fields' => array(
      'AccHead',
      'SUM(DebitAmount) as TotalDebit',
      'SUM(CreditAmount) as TotalCredit'),
  'group' => 'AccHead');
```

Comment: No reason to recommend using a manual query when the standard/ideal way to do it works just fine.

Comment: There are lots of way to solve the problem its just one of them. ya its just fine but cakephp also provides to do like this